# Reindex price only for specific store

Tags: magento-1.9, price, reindex

When I import special_price on a specific store, I would like reindex price only for this store.

I found this :

> Mage::getSingleton('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex(null, null, $store);

But that reindex all indexes.

I also found this :

> $indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
>
> $process = $indexer->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
>
> $process->reindexEverything();

But that reindex for all stores.

So I would like a mix of both solutions : reindex for specific index and specific store.

Do you know if it's possible and how ?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: No, I don't, sorry :(